# How to get id as integer from on_change method?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

I want to select distinct values with an sql query, for that I need id as integer.

My code is:

```
@api.onchange('qty')
def _on_change_name(self):
    logging.warning(self.id)
```

The printed id is `<openerp.models.NewId object at 0x7fc37d880490>`

How can I get integer from this `id` ?

Comment: Does `help(self.id)` or `dir(self.id)` give you any hints?

Comment: Why do you need that id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are creating a new record in a model with computed fields or in a onchange method, the records of the recordset will be in memory only. At that time the id of the record will be a dummy ids of type `openerp.models.NewId`

So if you need to use the record id in your code (e.g. for a sql query) you should check if it is available:

```
if isinstance(current_record.id, models.NewId):
    # do your stuff
```

**Update**. Zoellner has a better answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49152042/4891717)

> Take a look into [onchange() line 4971 and
>   following](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/f95566f08ae726402e7f1de70c1f5c042337c180/odoo/models.py#L4971).
>   Odoo is creating a new record in cache/memory and will later, after
>   the onchange is done, update the own cache with the provided data.
>
> If you really need the ID or other fields use
>   `<record>._origin.<field>`.
>
> **Note**: Don't use `api.one` decorator on onchange methods. They are
>   triggered on singleton records anyway.

Comment: I want to use it in  SQL queries..

Comment: If the id is not in the database you cannot use a SQL query

Comment: yes. if i have `Newid` how to get an integer ?

Comment: I think that's not posible because the data is not in the database yet. Then there is no an id assigned to the record. Sorry. If you tell me why you need to make the query maybe I can help you

Comment: I added a `real_id` field and set its value in `create()`. Now I can use it instead of `self.id`.