# What's happening with these transient models' IDs?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

**THE CODE**

I have the following transient models:

```
class MoveLotsManager(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'move.lots.manager'

    product_lots_available = fields.One2many(
        comodel_name='move.product.lot.available',
        inverse_name='manager_id',
        string='Available lots',
    )

class MoveProductLotAvailable(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'move.product.lot.available'

    manager_id = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name='move.lots.manager',
        string='Lots Manager',
    )
    name = fields.Char(
        string='Name',
    )

    @api.one
    @api.onchange('name')
    def onchange_name(self):
        # LOGGER 4
        _logger.info(self.manager_id)
        # LOGGER 5
        _logger.info(self.manager_id.id)
```

As you can see, they both are connected through a 1:N relationship. I open the transient models' views this way:

```
@api.multi
def open_move_lots_manager_wizard(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    wizard_id = self.env.ref(
        'my_module.view_move_lots_manager_wizard').id
    default_lots = [(
        (0, 0, {
            'name': 'My lot',
        })
    )]
    lots_manager = self.env['move.lots.manager'].create({
        'product_lots_available': default_lots,
    })
    # LOGGER 1
    _logger.info(lots_manager)
    # LOGGER 2
    _logger.info(lots_manager.id)
    # LOGGER 3
    _logger.info(lots_manager.product_lots_available.mapped('manager_id'))
    return {
        'name': _('Lots manager'),
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_id': False,
        'res_id': lots_manager.id,
        'views': [(wizard_id, 'form'), ],
        'res_model': 'move.lots.manager',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'target': 'new',
        'flags': {
            'form': {
                'action_buttons': False,
            },
        },
    }
```

**MY PURPOSE**

In the `onchange_name` method of the model `move.product.lot.available`, I want to access to its related manager (and their fields).

**THE EXPECTED BEHAVIOUR**

Imagine the `move.lots.manager` I've just created has the ID 11.

```
LOGGER 1: move.lots.manager(11,)
LOGGER 2: 11
LOGGER 3: move.lots.manager(11,)
LOGGER 4: move.lots.manager(11,)
LOGGER 5: 11
```

**THE CURRENT BEHAVIOUR**

```
LOGGER 1: move.lots.manager(11,)
LOGGER 2: 11
LOGGER 3: move.lots.manager(11,)
LOGGER 4: move.lots.manager(<openerp.models.NewId object at 0x7fd1a60cb850>,)
LOGGER 5: <openerp.models.NewId object at 0x7fd1a60cb850>
```

**MY QUESTION**

I know that transient models aren't stored in a permanent way, they're removed after a while, according to the system parameters of the database. But, while they're in the database, they do have an ID. And I can get it as you see, in fact, when I have the transient model form opened (with the developer mode activated) and I click on *View Metadata* option, I can see *ID: 11*... So why can't I get it from the "child" transient model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look into [onchange() line 4971 and following](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/f95566f08ae726402e7f1de70c1f5c042337c180/odoo/models.py#L4971). Odoo is creating a new record in cache/memory and will later, after the onchange is done, update the own cache with the provided data.

If you really need the ID or other fields use `<record>._origin.<field>`.

EDIT: Don't use `api.one` decorator on onchange methods. They are triggered on singleton records anyway.

Comment: Do you mean to write inside `onchange` method `_logger.info(self._origin.manager_id)` instead of `_logger.info(self.manager_id)`? I think I understood it wrong because it's giving this error: *'move.product.lot.available' object has no attribute '_origin'*

Comment: Yes `_logger.info(self._origin.manager_id)` should give you the ID. New lines in your "Manager" won't have a `manager_id` or an origin, if they weren't persisted to database (e.g. by pushing a button).

Comment: But they're persisted to the database inside `open_move_lots_manager_wizard` method, in this line: `lots_manager = self.env['move.lots.manager'].create({'product_lots_available': default_lots, })`, aren't they? Once the wizard view is opened, I don't add any lines (in fact I want users to work only with the lines I add before opening the wizard).

Comment: Yes, then it should work. Weird. On which "Logger" did you test the `_origin`?

Comment: The number 4, I replaced `_logger.info(self.manager_id)` with `_logger.info(self._origin.manager_id)`. I also showed with `dir` all the attributes and methods of `self` inside that `onchange` method, and `_origin` seems to be absent.

Comment: Can you remove the `@api.one` decorator and test it again?

Comment: That was the problem! If I remove `@api.one` I can access `_origin` variable and all the fields of the current record. Thank you very much @CZoellner for your efforts.