# How to get the value of `write_date` to a variable

Tags: datetime, odoo, odoo-10

In odoo every model will be having a `write_date` column which will store the last edited time and date of the record.I want to take the value of that field to a variable/ field. But when I print this , it is printing `False` . What to do.?

**code**

```
variable = self.write_date
```

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Which recordset do you have in `self`?

Comment: you mean model right ? 
Iam using a custom module and a custom model is used .. @forvas

Comment: Just before your line (`variable = self.write_date`), add this: `_logger.info(self)`, and write me the result of this line in the log file.

Comment: ocean_5_may odoo.addons.orchid_travels_v10.models.orchid_inbound: orchid.inbound(<odoo.models.NewId object at 0x7fe0c05717d0>,)

@forvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though we can see a field named write_date in the table,  First of all, what we have to do is that you have to add a field named write_date into your model and then try the same.

`write_date = fields.Datetime(string='Write Date')` solved my problem.Thanks everyone for helping.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're getting in `self` a new recordset (*odoo.models.NewId object at 0x7fe0c05717d0*). Therefore, you're trying to get the `write_date` of a record which has not been created yet. If the record has never been updated (even not created), it's not going to have a value in `write_date`.

Remember that `write_date` stores the latest date in which the record was updated.

So, first, at least, you must create the record, and then, you will be able to apply this: `variable = self.write_date`.

But take a look at this:

[What's happening with these transient models' IDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49150330/whats-happening-with-these-transient-models-ids)

May be you get the `write_date` without creating the record, give a try to this: `variable = self._origin.write_date`.